# Using custom data-* attributes inside HTML5 <template> tag

Tags: html, polymer

I'm building a menu with a dom-repeat template like this:

```
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{appletsMenu}}">
              <a data-route="{{item.dataRoute}}" href="{{item.href}}">
                <iron-icon icon="{{item.icon}}" src="{{item.iconSrc}}" ></iron-icon>
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
              </a>
        </template>
```

The `data-route` attribute is not filled though in the generated DOM:

```
<a href="...">...</a>
<a href="...">...</a>
```

It seems that the template only renders "normal" attributes like `href`. Am I'm missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you can use any custom attribute: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#defaultattrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to an attribute, use $= rather than =. This results in a call to:

```
element.setAttribute(attr, value);
```

As opposed to:

```
element.property = value;
```

[(source)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding)

So in your case:

```
<a data-route$="{{item.dataRoute}}" href="{{item.href}}">
```